# AWS Glue upload JSON : putObject: AccessDenied: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam, aws-glue

I have downloaded the AWS glue script from my Dev environment by clicking "Download" as a JSON file which include Job parameter and other info as well other than the code.

When i upload to my production environment by clicking "uplaod" for the json file. It succeed and all the job parameters are set automatically like DEV. However, when I clicked "Save", Error pops up

[uploading error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB6DV.png)

My IAM role below:

[IAM role](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKGVd.png)

My S3 bucket policy:

[S3 bucket policy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHfY0.png)

I am the bucket owner as well.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpKuR.png)

why am i failed?

Thanks a lot. It annoyed me for a week.

Please tell me where i am wrong and how can i fix it

Answer (score 0):

In your S3 bucket policy, I saw you had `"Principal": {"Service": "glue.amazonaws.com"}`, you're granting permissions to the AWS Glue service to perform certain actions on your S3 bucket

Maybe you have to grant access to that AWS service or yourself.
Try adding `"Principal": "*"` to your S3 bucket policy and check if it's working.

If it is, you need to grant access to your IAM user or the service role you're using for that operation.

Answer (score 0):

i have found that the ARN of the JSON file in different environment are different. So I tried to change it and upload to different environment and successful. Thank you for your attention and I will close this quetsion.